# Spring Boot Gracefully shutdown - Data Source closed before the completion of the Job

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot

I have implemented a scheduled job using the Spring boot application. This background scheduled job performs some database operations. Now the issue is that on shutting down the application the job keep continues its processing but the connection to the dataSource closed.

```
  @Scheduled(cron = "...............")
  public void process() {
       .      
  }
```

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

Can anyone please help me in resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I try to give some suggestion to resolve your issue.If it doesn’t help you, please forgive me.

**Method：** Before application shut down,we need first stop all tasks.

**Problem：** Task can't be canceled or stop.In this case we have not good way to graceful stop executed task.
**Assume：** Task can be stopped.

**Step1: We need to manage all task in application.**

In order to manage task in application，we need to implement `ThreadPoolTaskScheduler` and override task execute method.The below code is a simple example.

```
@Service
public class CustomTaskScheduler extends ThreadPoolTaskScheduler {
    private final Map<Object, ScheduledFuture<?>> scheduledTasks = new IdentityHashMap<>();

    public void cancelTask(Object identifier) {
        ScheduledFuture future = scheduledTasks.get(identifier);
        if (null != future) {
            System.out.println("future is not null");
            future.cancel(true);
        }
    }
    
    public void cancelAllTask() {
        scheduledTasks.values().forEach(future -> future.cancel(true));
    }
    
    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, long period) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> future = super.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, period);

        ScheduledMethodRunnable runnable = (ScheduledMethodRunnable) task;
        // Scheduled annotation only can used for no arguments method so hashCode plus method name is unique.
        scheduledTasks.put(runnable.getTarget(), future);

        return future;
    }
    
    @Override
    public ScheduledFuture<?> scheduleAtFixedRate(Runnable task, Date startTime, long period) {
        ScheduledFuture<?> future = super.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, startTime, period);

        ScheduledMethodRunnable runnable = (ScheduledMethodRunnable) task;
        // Scheduled annotation only can used for no arguments method so hashCode plus method name is unique.
        scheduledTasks.put(runnable.getTarget(), future);
        return future;
    }
}
```

**Step2:Stop all task before application shut down。**

*First method：* stop task before CustomTaskScheduler bean destroied. Add below code to CustomTaskScheduler

```
@PreDestroy
public void clear() {
    cancelAllTask();
}
```

*Second method：* If you can get application shut down signal then call CustomTaskScheduler's `cancelAllTask()` method。

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already tried with the PostDestroy, the connection to the database closed before reaching this method.

Comment: when connection to the database closed,do we can get some message,if we can then wo can stop execute new task,and stop processing task(if task can rollback,it is good)